# php check form input type like css (input[type=password])

Tags: php, forms, security, session

I have a redirect method that I usually run after a script has executed:

```
public static function redirect($to=http_referer){
    if($_POST){$_SESSION['post']=$_POST;}  //  <-- storing the $_POST values
    if(substr($to,0,1 )==="#"){$to=http_referer.$to;}
    if(!headers_sent()){return exit(header('Location:'.$to));} 
    else{return print_r('<script>window.location = "'.$to.'";</script>');}
}
```

As you can see, I'm storing the `$_POST` values in a session to make the values available after the user has been redirected. This is if something went wrong, and I redirect the user back to the previous page.

I have another method like so:

```
public static function _POST($post=null){
    if(empty($post)){ return $_SESSION['post']; }
    else { return $_SESSION['post'][$post]; }
}
```

This way I can have this is my form:

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="<?=KD::_POST('username')?>">  //  'KD' is the class name
```

...and the value will we filled inn with whatever the user entered before the redirect.
But I come to think that this might not be a good idea if the input type is "password".

Is there another, better and/or more secure way to dealing with this sort of thing?

Comment: Seems secure to me, because the session is not accessible on the user side.

Comment: why wouldn't it be a good idea? the password's in html that's on the user's computer, so it's note like you're printing out the password and hanging it on ever lamppost in the area.

Comment: I just thought that the session might be hacked of some sort, and then that the password could be stolen.. But it might not be a security issue?